# 「定規」と「物差し」の違いは何ですか

Tags: word-choice, words

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 定規 = *straightedge*
- 物差し = *ruler*

Now, consult an [English resource](https://www.reference.com/math/ruler-different-straightedge-3f3fa91ce1e6d254) :)

> *The primary difference between a ruler and straightedge is that a ruler is a measurement device, whereas a straightedge is a tool for drawing or viewing straightness. A ruler is a straightedge with some scale on it so that it can act not only as a straightedge, but also as a device to measure distance. Therefore, a ruler is a straightedge, but a straightedge is not necessarily a ruler.*

That said, practically all [定規](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E5%AE%9A%E8%A6%8F&tbm=isch) are sold with measuring scale (which has no legal warranty), it's safe to say both are synonyms in daily language.

cf. [compass-and-straightedge construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass-and-straightedge_construction) = [ruler-and-compass construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruler-and-compass_construction)

Answer (score 1):

物差し{ものさし}：For measuring the length of something.

定規{じょうぎ}：For drawing lines or curves.

Comment: DV激しいですけど、回答者は多分[これ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%9A%E8%A6%8F#.E5.AE.9A.E8.A6.8F.E3.81.A8.E7.89.A9.E5.B7.AE.E3.81.97.E3.81.AE.E9.81.95.E3.81.84)とか[これ](http://www.masa-web.com/name/etc/e023.html)みたいな感じのページ(もしくは辞書？)をご覧になったんじゃないですかね。。